# SSRS Reports: Drill down with custom columns in each sub-grouping

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, drilldown

I want to be able to group information (no problem) but be able to show a completely different set of columns when the grouping icon ('+') is selected.  For Instance, lets say the top level report is:

DEPARTMENT | MANAGER | BUDGET # | TOTAL SALES

Expand DEPARTMENT and get

MANAGERS | COST CENTER | NUM EMPLOYEES | Q1 SALES | Q2 SALES | Q3 SALES | Q4 SALES | ANNUAL TARGET

and so forth; there could be one or 2 more drill downs each with different columns.  Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, name the textboxes containing the top level items.

[image: Text Box Properties]

If you right click on the group that you want to be toggled by the top level report item and select 'Group properties', you can select visibility and there is an option for 'Display can be toggled by this report item' If you click the dropdown, you should be able to find the names of the textboxes.

[image: Group properties]

Repeat this for each of the groups, and the textboxes that you want to toggle them. 'When the report is initially run' does exactly what it says on the tin, so set it appropriately.